# Silverlight Encoder Templates, is it possible to change the background colour?

Tags: silverlight, video, expression-blend, encoder

Is it possible to change the default background colour of black in Silverlight Encoder Templates?

We have a website that requires a white background, instead of the default black bars for aspect ratio video.

I'm using Expression Studio 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be possible at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Blend by modificating the Encoder Template.

1.
      Left mouse click to your Silverlight Encoder in the Objects and Timeline pane (normally on the left, down to the project pane )

2.
      Select "Edit Template" -> "Edit a Copy"

3.
      Fill in the dialog Box

4.
      in the Objects and Timeline pane you will now the your Encoder Template and be able to change any property of it for creating your custom Encoder Template derivating from encoder.

Hope it helps.

Bastien BESSON

Comment: It is the background of the video container I'm interested in manipulating.